# I ran out of space on /boot - but have two /boot; How can I merge the empty one with the full one to have more space?

Tags: 16.04, boot, boot-repair

I ran out of space on /boot - but have two /boot; How can I merge the empty one with the full one to have more space? And then how do I properly run grub and reboot to boot from the newly combined spacious /boot? Thank you.

Comment: There cannot be two files or directories with the same name whithin the same directory `/`. What does `ls -ld /bo*` show?

Comment: $ ls -ld /bo*
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 27 12:39 /boot

Two partitions named "boot" I suppose. Can I merge them both somehow and make one larger /boot which still works? How?